# how to make php script use a list of proxies

Tags: php

Im using the Google pagerank checking script found here:

http://www.off-soft.net/en/develop/php/prcheck.html

I've noticed however that after too many requests the server gets a temporary ban.

I'd like to somehow route requests through a list of proxy servers - can anyone get me started?

I'm looking for any code examples of php requests using a list of proxies.

Thanks!!

Comment: Just a note, google probably knows most of the proxies out there and has them banned as well. Your best bet is to try a few before diving into a script like this. If they are banned, no need to waste your time trying to circumvent it.

Comment: @premiso Google doesn't care.  There aren't enough malicious people like this to spend money to stop it. Even though i agree, it is trivial to detect.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888667/php-and-rotating-proxies, your answer is probably there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PHP's curl](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) library allows you to use socks5 and http proxies.  A list of proxy servers should be verified using a tool like [YAPH](http://yaph.sourceforge.net/) before using them.

Answer (score 3):

The temporary ban is to prevent abuse. Using proxies to bypass the ban isn't exactly a nice thing to do. So, you're not likely to find anyone here who'll help you violate that site's TOS.

That being said, a proxy for HTTP is just a webserver that'll process/honor requests for foreign/outside URLs and return the results. The rest is left as an exercise to the asker.

Answer (score 0):

**Sample PHP CURL request using a Squid Proxy:**

```
$proxy = "1.1.1.1:12121";
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";
$url = "http://www.google.pt/search?q=anonymous";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,'CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD,'USER:PASS');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$useragent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Learn how to implement your own squid proxy with rotating outgoing ip's [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888667/php-and-rotating-proxies/)