# Changing IP address of CURL request on multi IP server

Tags: php, linux, curl, ip

I have a dedicated Linux server which has several IP addresses on it. When I'm making CURL requests with PHP it is done by it's primary IP address by default. I want to ask if there is a CURL parameter where I can change the requester IP to another IP addrresses that are on my server.

Answer (score 1):

Install squid proxy in your server ,and then setting the outgoing ip to rotate the ips.

you won't have to use CURLOPT_PROXY option anymore

check here:
[PHP and rotating proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888667/php-and-rotating-proxies)
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-squid-proxy-set-tcp_outgoing_address/